# Long text fields in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

First of all apologies for the noobish question, i'm fairly experienced in other areas of programming but i'm in the middle of teaching myself web development.

I'm building a website that is going to have `articles`. I know how to connect to the site to a mysql table and can build sites based on a query i.e. so I have a site called `something.com/articles?articleid="123456"`

Using MySQL tables i can populate all the headings, metadata and everything else for each article, the problem I have is the main body of text, I am reluctant to do (for example) `varchar(2000)` partly because on most occasions this will be overkill and on rare occasions it might not be enough.

Again apologies if i've made a wrong assumption along the way, i've picked up what I know about web developments mainly from guesswork and trial and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use MySQL's [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) data type. This type can [hold up to 65,535 characters](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/maximum-length-mysql-text-field-types/). If you need more, there are also `MEDIUMTEXT` and even `LONGTEXT` types (though `LONGTEXT` will probably overkill in most situations).

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on having a ton of text in one column, you may want to consider storing the text in a file instead. The files could be placed in a special directory just for them, and named by their respective Article ID.

For example, if article #12345 was requested by a user, MySQL would provide the metadata/header/etc for the article, then PHP would retrieve 12345.txt in that special directory and display it.